# how can i show images in d3 nodes circle im trying blow code but its not working

Tags: d3.js

```
 var node = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(responseJSON.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "logo")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .style("fill", "transparent")       
    .style("stroke", "black")     
    .style("stroke-width", 0.25)
    .style("fill", "url('https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100')");
```

can any one help showing the image
[html screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbcvV.png)

Comment: have you tried changing fill as attribue ?`.attr("fill", "url('https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100')")`

Comment: yes its not worked